# How to style a completely different element when hovering over another element(with different parents)?

Tags: html, css

I know how to change elements while hovering over a different element, but what I want to know is can I actually change the styling of an element that is in a completely different parent than the hovered element rather that using + or > ...ect to style siblings and stuff. So for example if i had an HTML structure like this

```
<div id="firstParent">

     <div id="firstParentInner">
         <a id="hoverMe">Hello world</a>
     </div>

</div>


<div id="randomDiv"></div>


<div id="changeMyInner">
      <div id="changeMyChild">
         <div id="changeMe"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Can I change the styles of id changeMe by hovering over hoverMe which just CSS

so the CSS would kind of be like

```
#firstParent #hoverMe:hover ~ #changeMyInner #changeMe{
     background: red;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: No....there is no CSS selector that will let you do that. You need Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short - no.

There are 3 possible scenarios:

Element directly inside parent:

```css
#container:hover > .column { background-color: black; }
```

If element is next to other element:

```css
.column:hover + .column { background-color: black; }
```

And if element is somewhere inside parent ,anywhere:

```css
#container:hover .element { background-color: black; }
```

Thats about it.

Comment: ok thanks, worth a shot!

Comment: np, if you can accept answer to close this question, would be good.

Best,
Goran